# Lambda expression to convert list int to list string in c#

Tags: c#, lambda

Lambda expression to convert list int to list string

```
List<int> lstNum = new List<int>(new int[] { 3, 6, 7, 9 });
```

Comment: one solution could be `List<string> newList = lstNum.Select(i => Convert.ToString(i)).ToList();`

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following to convert a List of int to a List of string:

```
List<string> lstStr = lstNum.ConvertAll<string>(x => x.ToString());
```

Comment: The <string> is unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

This will work as well:

```
List<string> lstString = lstNum.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for lambda:

```
var lstNum = new [] { 3, 6, 7, 9 }.ToList();

var lstStr = lstNum.ConvertAll(Convert.ToString);
```